# SSH transparent jump to next server

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to somehow redirect the SSH connection depending on the user?

For example
I have 3 machines
proxy, host1, host2

And I would like the user john logging into proxy (ssh john@proxy_ip) automagically logging into host1
user alice (ssh alice@proxy_ip) automagically logged into host2

Users are not supposed to know where they are redirected.
so ssh -J john@proxy_ip john@host1 is not a solution

Does ssh have these options? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use an ssh_config `Match user` for Host proxy to set different Hostnames for bob and alice - however afaik they would be able to see the ultimate destination (in password prompts, diagnostic messages and so on)

Answer (score 2):

You might configure each user account on the proxy host with a custom "shell" that is actually a script that will make a SSH connection to a specific user account on the specific background host.

Such a script would essentially be:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ssh ${USER}@hostX  #replace hostX with actual host name here
```

To set them as shells, you would probably have to list the script for each destination host in `/etc/shells`, and then just assign them to the user accounts on the proxy host:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/ssh-to-host1 john
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/ssh-to-host2 alice
```

If you do this, you should also set up SSH keys for the proxy->hostX jump, or otherwise ensure that the second connection gets seamlessly authenticated.

Because of the `exec`, there would be no shell process to return to after the ssh to hostX has started, so when that ssh session ends, the user would automatically get logged out of the proxy too.

This is not perfect, as the destination hosts will still reveal their actual hostname (unless you pull a "Spartacus" and set all their hostnames to identical to the proxy host, which might cause other issues).

Comment: I am just starting to test this solution. I will combine this with https://www.freeipa.org/

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you can edit the `.ssh/config` of the user accounts you want to redirect to.
So the `/home/alice/.ssh/config` will look like this:

```
Host proxy_ip
 User alice
 HostName host2
```

And `/home/john/.ssh/config`:

```
Host proxy_ip
 User john
 HostName host1
```

Comment: Something to be noted is that even if for their user experience they'll not see the difference, if either of them ask `ssh` to be more verbose using the `-v` flag, they'll find out which host they're connecting to, I think there's no way to avoid that.